# Why does Krol Rudy care about spilling the blood of animals so much?

Tags: yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer, the-king-of-the-fields

In Isaac Bashevis Singer's *The King of the Fields*, Krol Rudy mentions that he doesn't want the blood of animals to be spilled:

> An odd thought began to take shape in his mind; when he died, he would like to be buried and to have a field planted over his bones. Perhaps man would stop shedding the blood of animals and nourish himself on the bounties of soil, sun, rain.
> <sub>*The King of the Fields*, part 1, chapter 1, section 3 (translated by the author)</sub>

Why does Krol Rudy care so much about this, especially since he's personally killed a lot of people? This comes directly after he a scene where he sexually assaults a young girl and wants to kill her, so the contrast is... rather jarring.